# Can I put an Intent Service into a library project and use it in different apps?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Im working on a library with an Intent Service. I want to use this IntentService in different apps, that probably are installed in parallel on the users device.

Let's assume I have two android applications. Both use my library and want to use my IntentService (part of the library). **I dont want to make something like a "shared service"**, both apps are independed, both service should run independent from each other.

In the first apps Android Manifest I specify the service as follows:

```
<service android:name="com.mylibrary.service.SuperService" android:enabled="true"/>
```

In the second app I will do the same:

```
<service android:name="com.mylibrary.service.SuperService" android:enabled="true"/>
```

Does it make conflicts, because both apps have the same package and name? Does Android know which SuperService instance belongs to which app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there will not be any conflict with that scenes each process running independently it own instances,  and the fact that both of them running same service name (and package name)  don't cause any problem.

I know that for sure, simply because **I'm doing the same thing myself** for a long time - using same library Service in two different apps that runs simultaneity on same device

under the hood, `Service` is simply implemented as kind of singltone  that the OS manage it lifecyle in special way then other Java classes, but eventually it's still an instance running inside your own process memory sandbox.

Same with `IntentService`, that extends `Service`

Comment: @Doctoror Drive says in his answer that they will share the same instance

Comment: @sockeqwe:  then he is wrong, or did not understood your question. I think he thought you want to do remote service that shared to both apps.

Comment: you welcome,   simple test applications can show you that it's true, don't believe blindly to strangers  :->

Comment: What about BroadCast receivers? Defining one in the libray project and include it into many apps should work as well, right? Have you any experience with that?

Comment: @sockeqwe: no problem also with broadcast receivers.   Also from experience

Answer (score 1):

You can make it, but the Service will have the same instance for all apps.
To use an exported Service of another application you don't have to declare it in client application's manifest.

Declare an exported Service in a library as follows

```
<service android:name="com.mylibrary.service.SuperService"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mylibrary.service.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING" />
        <action android:name="com.mylibrary.service.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_ELSE" />
        <action android:name="com.mylibrary.service.ACTION_SOME_OTHER_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

To start a Service with specific operation in any application, use

```
context.startService(new Intent("com.mylibrary.service.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING"));
```

The Android will search for installed applications that have services that can handle the action based on intent-filters. Once found, the service is started.

Then check for these actions in onHandleIntent() and run the code you need.

Comment: Are you sure that they will share the same instance? Because @Tal Kanel says in his answer that it will work just fine

Comment: I think @TalKanel is speaking of a Service that is in a **library project** used in different apks, but I'm talking about a separate APK containing the serivce that is started from another APK. As far as I understood that's what you wanted.

Comment: Ah, now I got you meant by "I dont want to make something like a "shared service". I thought it meant you don't want a single instance to run, but making it running from different APK.

Answer (score 0):

These two thing can't be same

**com.mylibrary.service.SuperService

and

com.mylibrary.service.SuperService**

because for both of your application installed your package name will be different.

If your application have a library then also be it has different context of application run. They won't conflict ever.

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem .

```
 public void startService(Context context ){
    if(!isServiceRunning(  context )) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAppService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    } 
}

public boolean isServiceRunning(Context context ) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyAppService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {

            // bug in here 
            //chack service name . 
            //and need check package name 
            //debug app a service name => org.app.myappservice
            //debug app b service name => org.app.myappservice
            //debug app a package name of service => com.esf.app 
            //debug app b package name of service => com.teh.test
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

i change code to

```
public void startService(Context context ){
    if(!isServiceRunning(  context )) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAppService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}

public boolean isServiceRunning(Context context ) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyAppService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName()) && service.service.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("com.example.app2")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```